# Design: Designing a Status Tracking Tool

Tags: design, object-oriented-design, api-design, class-design, software

We have a robust set of micro-services available.

For simplicity, let us call the services

```
S1
S2
S3
S4
S5
```

For simplicity, think of the flow to be this.

```
S1 -> performs step1 (start step)
S2 -> performs step2
S2 -> performs step3
S3 -> performs step4
S4 -> performs step5
S5 -> performs step6 (final step)
```

Now, for tracking if a particular activity is complete or not, we need to call the status check API in each of these 5 services. (5 to 6 APIs sequentially ie.)

I am building another service `SS1` to track this flow.  `SS1` would basically call S1 , S2, S3 , S4 , S5 with different inputs too to track the current status.

I am looking for scalable designs to solve this problem addressing the various concerns.

Here are a few assumptions/requirements:

1. We could assume the total number of external services to be called will <=5.
2. This is more like an internal tool. The infra cost should be as less as possible.
3. My Cloud Platform is AWS.

What I have now is:

I am making it stateless (not saving any info in DB) just because all these are read-only and primarily for internal purposes.

I have a class model like the following:

[image]

One could think that the API exposes a nested JSON with the above relationships in a single API per activity. The steps array will have a state machine schema to include (start, next, end etc.)

So, here are the things I want feedback on:

1. Stateless vs Stateful - will this choice have any side effects?
2. Sync Response vs Async (response of the `SS1`) - can I make it async somehow?. My goal is that the frontend should not know/ store these steps?
3. The above relationship diagram - does it work for the problem.
4. What is the infra support needed to build this. This is an internal tool, I need to focus more on the output quality, a bit of delayed response is acceptable.
   With this being the case, Where do I host this on? EC2,Lamda etc? Any other out of the box solutions?

Also, let me know if further details are needed. I have kept the problem and solution on a high level specifically.

Answer (score 0):

> Stateless vs Stateful - will this choice have any side effects?

On a `stateless` approach if anything goes wrong with the instance running it, you'll lose everything. Do you mind?. Also, payloads could eventually get big as you need to keep everything on requests.

> Sync Response vs Async - can I make it async somehow?. My goal is that the frontend should not know/ store these steps?

You mean the response of `SS1`?

> The above relationship diagram - does it work for the problem.

Looks ok.

Finally, what about using a message queue?